# Where does Hyperledger Sawtooth store its ledger?

Tags: hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-sawtooth

Where does Hyperledger Sawtooth store its ledger entries within the validator? Is it in a readable format?

What kind of a database does it maintain?

Can the transactions performed on the network be seen?

Comment: Yes, all transactions and their meta data are visible.

Answer (score 3):

By default, the blockchain is stored under `/var/lib/sawtooth/` unless you have `$SAWTOOTH_HOME` set, then it uses that directory.

The blockchain (transactions) is stored as a sparse file in a LMDB database in file `block-00.lmdb` . The global state (variables) is stored in file `merkle-00.lmdb` as a Merkle Trie.

More details in the FAQ at https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/faq/validator/#what-files-does-sawtooth-use

Answer (score 2):

> Where does Hyperledger Sawtooth store its ledger entries within the
>   validator?

From the [docs](https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/releases/1.0/architecture/global_state.html):

*Sawtooth represents state for all transaction families in a single instance of a Radix Merkle Tree on each validator.*

> Is it in a readable format?

Depends what you mean by readable. The [only information](https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/releases/1.0/sysadmin_guide/configuring_sawtooth/validator_configuration_file.html) I could find says that Sawtooth uses the [OpenTS](http://opentsdb.net/) database. This is [readable](http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/user_guide/query/index.html) (with a learning curve).

However it states that this database is used "for metrics". It is not clear what this means.